# something open to somebody

Tags: usage

The following is a headline

> Brazil’s Bolsonaro open to G7 aid if Macron ‘withdraws insults’

[For More Information](https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/brazils-bolsonaro-open-to-g7-aid-if-macron-withdraws-insults/article29270897.ece?homepage=true)

I think it should be

> G7 aid open to Brazil's Bolsonaro if Macron withdraws insults.

Comment: Have you looked up “open” to see if there are any definitions that match the sentence as written?

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference in meaning.

> Brazil’s Bolsonaro open to G7 aid if Macron ‘withdraws insults’

This means Bolsonaro won't take the aid until Macron withdraws insults.

> G7 aid open to Brazil's Bolsonaro if Macron withdraws insults.

This means Bolsonaro can't get the aid unless Macron withdraws insults.